# Python comtypes types issue

Tags: python, comtypes

I have this code:

```
import comtypes
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
certadmin = CreateObject("CertificateAuthority.Admin")
certadmin._ICertAdmin2__com_GetArchivedKey('hostname\\simpleca', 35, 'CR_OUT_BASE64', comtypes.BSTR(' '))
```

However, I'm problems with a data type, e.g.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ArgumentError: argument 3: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A wild guess. The third argument of the [`GetArchivedKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method should be a number. You're passing the string `CR_OUT_BASE64`. Probably this should work:

```
certadmin._ICertAdmin2__com_GetArchivedKey('hostname\\simpleca', 35, 1, comtypes.BSTR(' '))
```

`CR_OUT_BASE64` constant is equal to 1.

Comment: Excellent, that works. Any Idea how I can use get the GetArchivedKey method to request the cert using its serial number instead of the request ID?